# Change a state of a control on another independent form, in the same application

Tags: forms, delphi

**Situation**:

- An application with 2 forms and 1 DataModule unit
- Both units containing the forms, have the DataModule in "uses". Unit containing the Form1 has the unit containing the Form2 in "uses"
- Form1 has two buttons on it
- Both forms are shown at the same time, Form1 is NOT a parent of the Form2, nor vice versa

**What I need**:

I need to be able to control the state of the two buttons on Form1, by actions on the Form2.

**What I did**:

I used a timer on the Form1, that continuously (250ms) checks a variable in the DataModule and based on it's value, it changes the state of the buttons on the Form1. Then I modify the variable in DataModule from the Form2.

The variable in DataModule:

```
public
  BtnToDisable: string;
```

The Timer on Form1:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  if Datamodule4.BtnToDisable = 'All' then
    for i := 0 to Form1.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Form1.Controls[i].ClassType = TButton then
        Form1.Controls[i].Enabled := False;
    end
  else if Datamodule4.BtnToDisable = 'None' then
    for i := 0 to Form1.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Form1.Controls[i].ClassType = TButton then
        Form1.Controls[i].Enabled := True;
    end
  else if Datamodule4.BtnToDisable = 'Button1' then
    for i := 0 to Form1.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Form1.Controls[i].Name = 'Button1' then
        Form1.Controls[i].Enabled := False;
    end
  else if Datamodule4.BtnToDisable = 'Button2' then
    for i := 0 to Form1.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Form1.Controls[i].Name = 'Button2' then
        Form1.Controls[i].Enabled := False;
    end;
end;
```

The action on the Form2:

```
DataModule4.BtnToDisable := 'All'     // All, None, "name"
DataModule4.BtnToDisable := 'Button1' // All, None, "name"
...
```

**The problem**:

Well, it works, but in a more complicated scenario, with a lot of buttons to be enabled/disabled, more forms, and more possible combinations (enable three specific buttons, disable all the other, etc.), it gets complicated, and hard to maintain. ***Is there a way to access those buttons on the Form1 directly, considering, that I don't have the Form1 object, accessible from the Form2?***

Comment: You don't need an arbitrator, like the data module. Since form1 knows form2, you can expose a structure from form2 that form1 fills in, like a button array for instance.

Comment: Why the complexity? The two units that define the forms can have access to the other. So in your form1 code you can access form2 directly, and vice versa. Not that this is necessarily a good idea but it would be a massive step up from your current code.

Comment: In other words, you say *Is there a way to access those buttons on the Form1 directly, considering, that I don't have the Form1 object, accessible from the Form2?* But you can easily have Form1 accessible from Form2.

Comment: Beyond all if that you don't want to use a timer at all. You want to use actions or action lists. Combine both of these observant your code will become clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always have access to every Form object, even if you don't `use` their units directly.  All created `TForm` objects are stored in the [`Forms[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.Forms) property of the global [`Screen`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.Screen) object in the `Forms` unit.

That being said, instead of using a `TTimer`, I would suggest using a `TAction(List).OnUpdate` or `TApplication(Events).OnIdle` event handler to perform the Button updates.  Those events are triggered whenever the main UI message loop finishes processing messages from the main message queue and goes idle waiting for new messages to arrive.  When you start dealing with multiple Forms that need updating, you can give each Form its own `TAction(List)` or `TApplicationEvents`.

I would also suggest defining an Enum to represent each button, and then change the `BtnToDisable` variable to be a `Set` of those Enum values. This way, you can disable any combination of Buttons you want.  Assign those Enum values to each Button's `Tag` property, or use a `Dictionary`, or a class helper, or any other means you want to associate an Enum value with a Button object. Then, when an Update is needed, you can simply loop through the Buttons, and if a given Button's associated Enum value is in the `Set` then disable that Button, otherwise enable it. No need to check `Name` properties at all.

And lastly, I would suggest having a Form store its Buttons in an array or `T(Object)List` that you can loop through, instead of looping through the Form's `Controls[]` property every time.

Comment: Easier to add Unit1 to the implementation section uses of Unit2.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "add Unit1 to the implementation section uses of Unit2" - this is THE answer to the original question. I am surprised how simple it is. I am going to combine it with Remy's suggestions. Thank you all